# Session Caching using Generic Static Methods

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developing web application to display credit card information to the user. I get card information from different web services, I am creating multiple objects to store these values. I was planning to store the objects in session by card number and function-name (Constant value to differentiate objects, for example ccInfo is the function-name for cardInformationObject)

I created a generic static class to achieve the same however that does not work as I have multiple types of object and C# will not allow to typecast object to generic type. See Code snippet below.

```
// Generic static class
  public class SessionCache<T>
  {
    public static T Add(string cardNumber, string functionName, T data)
    {
        var sessionKey = "${cardNumber}_{functionName}";
        if(HttpContext.Current != null && HttpContext.Current.Session != null)
        {
          HttpContext.Current.Session[sessionKey] = data;
        }
     }     

      public static T Get(string cardNumber, string functionName)
      {
        var sessionKey = "${cardNumber}_{functionName}";
        if(HttpContext.Current != null && HttpContext.Current.Session != null)
        {
          return HttpContext.Current.Session[sessionKey] as T; // This line throw errors because i am type casting to generic type
        }
      }     
   }
```

Now I am left with two options :

Create abstract class/ Interface, inherit all different response objects from that. Replace Generic T with abstract class / Interface.

Create Hash Table, add different objects in Hash Table. Store dictionary in session.

Which would be better option? is there any other approach for the same?

Comment: I don't know the full context, but I'd be very, very cautious with anything that stores credit card numbers in any form. If you're working with real credit card numbers it might be worth considering services that "tokenize" them. When the user enters the card it gets sent to a 3rd party. They store the real card number and return a token + the last 4. Your app never handles the real credit card. When you need to bill you do it through the provider that gave you the token. You send them the token and they bill the card with the real number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't type cast from generic type in this line:

```
return HttpContext.Current.Session[sessionKey] as T;
```

Because `as` operator may return null and your generic type could be a non-nullable type, e.g., you could call it as `SessionCache<int>`

You can define a constraint on your generic class:

```
public class SessionCache<T> where T : class
```

Alternatively, you may use a cast on the return statement:

```
return (T)HttpContext.Current.Session[sessionKey];
```

Keep in mind that the later solution may throw an `InvalidCastException` at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I like using a strongly typed wrapper like this:

```
public static class SN
{
    private static string CardNumber
    {
        get => (string)HttpContext.Current.Session["CardNumber"];
        set => HttpContext.Current.Session["CardNumber"] = value;
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that the session is suitable for storing data about the current user only. To store application-wide data use the `HttpContext.Current.Application` or the `HttpContext.Current.Cache`.